# How to make desktop icons display on startup of Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, .desktop, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons

Often when I start my PC the desktop icons do not display in the actual desktop.

To clarify, my shortcut launchers do not appear on my desktop but of course Nautilus and Thunar show them in the folder: `~/Desktop`. The missing items include launchers I created or were created for me by apps and also "Rubbish Bin" and my "Home" folder icon which was created through settings.

To date I have had to reboot or log out and re-login to fix.  The problem repeated this morning on start-up up from cold.

This is slow because I have startup background apps including: Conky, Dropbox, Mega and Universal Media Server.

Is there a quicker way?

Note: Possibly related but I continue to get strange behaviour whenever I edit a desktop launcher or create a new one. A bug registered as Bug #1878392

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "the desktop icons do not display **in Nautilus**"? They don't show up in Nautilus (aka the 'Files' application) or doesn't show up on the *actual* desktop? (Note that unlike some of the older releases, Nautilus *does not* handle desktop icons in 20.04, they're handled by a GNOME extension.)

Comment: Apologies.  I did not realise that Nautilus is not responsible for the desktop.  To clarify, my shortcut launchers do not appear on my desktop but of course Nautilus and Thunar show them in the folder: ~/Desktop.  The missing items include launchers I created or were created for me by apps and also "Rubbish Bin" and my "Home" folder icon which was created through settings.  

The problem repeated this morning on start-up up from cold.   My start up apps also include conky.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 here: [How to restart GUI on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-gui-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa) provides a faster workaround to this bug.

While logged in to your GNOME desktop press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> key combination. Into the *Enter a Command* box type **`r`** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This also works in 16.04 and 18.04 and doesn't force close any open windows or log out.